# Выпадающий список, даты на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь на JS сделать список с выпадающими датами (см. вложение).
Берется текущая дата, а точнее месяц и год, и от этой текущей даты должны отображаться будущие 12 месяцев и 3 прошедших месяца.
Вместо `undefined 2018` должно быть `Октябрь, Ноябрь и Декабрь 2017`.

Скрипт ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<script type="text/javascript">

Date.prototype.getMonthName = function(i) {
    var month = ['Январь','Февраль','Март','Апрель','Май','Июнь','Июль','Август','Сентябрь','Октябрь','Ноябрь','Декабрь'];
    return month[i];
}

var currentDate = new Date();
var cuurYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
var cuurMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
var objSelM = document.myForm.Month;
var objSelFM = document.myForm.FMonth;


window.onload = function selCuurDate(){ 
    var j = 0;

    for(var i = -3; i < 12; i++)    { 
        j = cuurMonth + i;      

        var y = 0;      
        if (j > 11) {
            j = j - 12;
            y = 1;
        }
        y = currentDate.getFullYear() + y;
        if (i == j){
            addOption(objSelM, currentDate.getMonthName(j) + " " + y, currentDate.getMonthName(j) + "_" + y, true, true);
            addOption(objSelFM, currentDate.getMonthName(j) + " " + y, currentDate.getMonthName(j) + "_" + y, true, true);

        } else {
            addOption(objSelM, currentDate.getMonthName(j) + " " + y, currentDate.getMonthName(j) + "_" + y, false, false);
            addOption(objSelFM, currentDate.getMonthName(j) + " " + y, currentDate.getMonthName(j) + "_" + y, false, false);

        }
    }

    OUT_IN.style.visibility = "hidden"
<!--    objSelM.selectedIndex = j;
<!--    objSelFM.selectedIndex = j;-->  
    objSelFM.width = 200;
    clickChg(objSelFM.value);

}     

function addOption (oListbox, text, value, isDefaultSelected, isSelected)
{
    var oOption = document.createElement("option");
    oOption.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    oOption.setAttribute("value", value);

    if (isDefaultSelected) oOption.defaultSelected = true;
    if (isSelected) oOption.selected = true;

    oListbox.appendChild(oOption);
}



</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте такую проверку для учета случаев, когда какие-то из трех предыдущих месяцев попадают в прошлый год:

```
if (j < 0) {
  j = j + 12;
  y = -1;
}
```